# Ionic website with couchdb blocked by companies' networks

Tags: ionic-framework, couchdb, firewall

I own a website which is an Ionic 3 web application, that uses CouchDB as Databases.
When people try to access the website behind some companies' networks, they can't login.
I think that the connection to the DB is refused by the firewall, even because when they try to access from their home network, everything works ok.
Is there something I can do to solve this?
CouchDB uses port 6984 over https.

Comment: Do clients send queries directly to your CouchDB server? Or do they send requests to web server and subsequently your web server sends queries to CouchDB?

Comment: It sends directly

Comment: I understand that the port `6984` is blocked by firewall, right?

Comment: That's what I think

Comment: It might be possible that the firewall admin has blocked all the ports except some whitelisted ones. One solution might be to send the client queries to web server and subsequently forward the queries from web server to your CouchDB server! Just an idea, not sure!